# Ajax carregar apenas div de uma pagina pela Class

Tags: jquery, ajax

Com ID eu consigo acho, fazendo assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "www.teste.com/recuperar-senha #senha",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.main').html("<p>Carregando...</p>");
    },
    success: function(r){
        $('.main').html(r);
    }

});
```

Mas se em meu arquivo não tiver um ID, como faço pra carregar apenas uma div pegando pela class?

Comment: Sua solução a cima deveria funcionar... está dando algum erro?

Comment: Funciona, mas minha pergunta é essa: "Mas se em meu arquivo não tiver um ID, como faço pra carregar apenas uma div pegando pela class?"

Comment: Agora acho que entendi

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas o que você quer fazer, se eu não me engano, é feito com `web crawler`

Comment: tenta assim $('.main')[0].html("<p>Carregando...</p>");

Comment: o seletor jquery qdo tem uma classe, normalmente vai retornar um array, pq pode ter várias class com esse nome

Comment: se não for isso, tenta usar foreach e dentro colocar essa expressão q vc quer do success